# Sql, Subquery into a LIKE() operator

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I'm using oracle 10g and i've a question for you.

Is it possible to "insert" a subquery into a `LIKE()` operator ?

Exemple : `SELECT* FROM users u WHERE u.user_name LIKE ( subquery here );`

What i've tried before ->

```
SELECT * FROM dictionary WHERE TABLE_NAME
LIKE (Select d.TABLE_NAME from dictionary d
      where d.COMMENTS LIKE '%table%'
     )
WHERE ROWNUM < 100;
```

It tolds me that my query didnt wokrs -> `ORA-00933: la commande SQL ne se termine pas correctement` (The sql query doesn't finish correctly) and the last `WHERE` is out.

I know this is a stupid query, but that just a question that i'm looking for an answer =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, why not?

```
SELECT * FROM users u WHERE u.user_name LIKE (select '%arthur%' from dual);
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/00016/2/0)

Answer (score 4):

I am guessing you want to do this because you want to compare multiple values at the same time.  Using a subquery (as in your example) won't solve that problem.

Here is another approach:

```
select *
from users u
where exists (<subquery here> where u.user_name like <whatever>)
```

Or using an explicit join:

```
select distinct u.*
from users u join
     (subquery here
     ) s
     on u.user_name like s.<whatever>
```

Answer (score 1):

IF your subquery return more than 1 row and if this row isn't a string it will not work in your case use `IN` instead of `LIKE`

Answer (score 1):

Only if your subquery returns one value